# qt5 how to get real width and height of qlabel?

Tags: qt, qt5, qlabel

How to get true width and height of QLabel? Methods width() and height() always returns 100 and 30. I want to put QLabel inside QPushButton, and then resize button to content of label, but my code doesn't work.

```
void MyTranslationButton::setFullTranslation( QString s_en_transl, QString s_ru_transl )
{
    QLabel* label = new QLabel( this );
    label->setText
        ( 
            "<span style=\"font-size: 24px; font-weight: bold;\" >" + s_en_transl + "</span><br/>" + 
            "<span style=\"font-size: 18px;\" ><i>" + s_ru_transl + "</i></span>"
        );
    label->setAttribute( Qt::WA_TransparentForMouseEvents, true );
    label->setAlignment( Qt::AlignCenter | Qt::AlignVCenter );
    
    QGridLayout* layout = new QGridLayout( this );
    this->setMinimumWidth( label->width() );
    this->setMinimumHeight( label->height() );
    this->setLayout( layout );
    this->layout()->addWidget( label );
}
```

Sorry for my english.

Comment: The real width/height can only be known when the widget is inside a layout and visible. Before it's impossible.

Comment: @chehrlic, that's sad

Comment: @chehrlic _The real width/height can only be known when the widget is inside a layout and visible._ It is not exactly like that. You can get the actual size of the widget in a resize event, even if it is not a part of a layout.

Comment: @КрошкаРу, `QWidget` has a `resizeEvent`. Reimplement it to know when and how the size changes.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like its impossible, so I calc QLabel content size with QFontMetrics.

```
//Вычислить ширину строки в пикселах
int MyTranslationButton::calcStringPixelWidth( QString s_str, QFont font, int n_font_size )
{
    font.setPointSize( n_font_size );
    QFontMetrics fm( font );
    return fm.width( s_str );
}


//Вычислить высоту строки в пикселах
int MyTranslationButton::calcStringPixelHeight( QFont font, int n_font_size )
{
    font.setPointSize( n_font_size );
    QFontMetrics fm( font );
    return fm.height();
}
```